# boto3 Python - Check if "directory" exists in S3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I'm trying to see if a specific "directory" exists in S3. I understand everything is an object and directories is a more or less a facade, but I have partitions (based on different days) and I want to verify if that day exists or not:

### Sample Code

```
def _is_valid_s3_path(bucket_name, partition_location):
    try:
        data = s3.list_objects_v2(Bucket=bucket_name, Delimiter='/', Prefix=partition_location)
        print(data)
        if 'KeyCount' in data and data['KeyCount'] > 0:
            return True
        else:
            return False

    except botocore.exceptions.ClientError as e:
        if e.response['Error']['Code'] == "404":
            raise
        else:
            print('err')
            print(e.response)
            raise
```

#### Sample Input Data

```
result = _is_valid_s3_path('my_bucket', 'event/data-information/year=2020/month=09/day=29/')
```

I want it to match that specific path (there are children, but I want to know if `day=29` exists. The code I have seems to not be working as expected.

Comment: No, that is pertinent to a bucket, which is not the question I am asking

Comment: Your code works as is if I make a bucket and make objects under `event/data-information/year=2020/month=09/day=29/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In S3 objects are identified by a key and these keys can have a prefix. In order to determine if a "directory" exists, we just have to find an object with the prefix for the given "directory" path.

```
def _is_valid_s3_path(bucket_name, path):
    s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
    bucket = s3.Bucket(bucket_name)
    return sum(1 for _ in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix=path)) > 0
```

Now I know that the AWS console has the option to create a folder:

[image]

What this is essentially doing is creating an empty file with the corresponding key. If we list the content of this "folder" from the AWS CLI, we will see that it is an object with the name of the folder and size of `0`.